# How to make a row non-clickable in Flutter DataTable

Tags: flutter, datatable

I have DataTable in Flutter like:
[image]

if I click in one of the rows, for example WELT row, it will be redirected to another page, and it is ok. But I want to make the last row (Gesamt) non-clickable.
is it possible?
my code block looks like:

```
DataRow(
               onSelectChanged: (bool) {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushNamed(DetailScreen.routeName, arguments: {
                      'pageType': 'Brand',
                      'id': brand['name_slug'].toString(),
                    });
                  },
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(Text(brand['name'])),
                    DataCell(
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(formatter.format(brand['goal'])),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(formatter.format(brand['ist_stichtag'])),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                 
                    
                  and so on
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AbsorbPointer to prevent any click on the row. Link for the docs regarding this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html